# RUBY ON RAILS QUERY FOR ASSOCIATION RELATION

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

```
class Persson
   has_many : accounts
   has_many : computers, through : :accounts
end

class Account
   belongs_to : person
   belongs_to : computer
   scope :administrtor, -> { where(role : 'administrator') }
end

class Computer
  has_many :accounts
  has_many :person, though: :accounts
end
```

1.Find all the computers where this person(id: 39) is an administrator.

2.Find all the persons who are the administrator in more than one computers.

3.Find all the computers where there is a single administrator.

Comment: This looks like homework. What have you already done to try to solve this problem?

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: this question was asked in an interview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey please check the association rails document [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)
Assuming you are using PostgreSQL following the solution to your problem

1.

```
Person.includes(:accounts).find(1).computers.where("accounts.role =?", 'administrator')
```

2.

```
Person.where(id: Account.administrtor.group("accounts.person_id").having("count(accounts.person_id) > 1").pluck("accounts.person_id"))
```

3.

```
Computer.where(id: Account.administrtor.group("accounts.computer_id").having("count(accounts.computer_id) = 1").pluck("accounts.computer_id"))
```